# WhatsApp messaging interrupts Music while the wireless headset is connected

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, music

I just discovered that when I tap the send button on WhatsApp the music stops for while. Actually it doesn't stop. The headsets goes silence for a second and then continues normally. The same thing happens when somebody sends a message to me. But, it doesn't happen when I receive messages while I'm on another screen. For example, at the very moment I'm writing this question and music plays on. I saw that I'm gathering new messages on notification area, but no problem occurs.

I'm using JBL TUNE 600BTNC Bluetooth headset.
My phone is Realme 3 Pro.
Android version is 9.
The music players I tried are VLC and PowerAmp.

Comment: Have you enabled notification sounds for whatsapp?

Answer (score 2):

you can try to change the settings `Sound->Earphone mode->Notification ringtone in earphones` to `never`. Downside: you won't get any notifications on your Headset anymore.
I hope it helps.

Edit: This setting is available in OxygenOS if anyone else is facing this problem

Comment: I couldn't find related settings

Comment: @ÇağlayanDÖKME but you are running Android 9 right?

Comment: Can the Realme UI affect the settings screen? Maybe, it is disabling some of them.

Comment: Oh that's right, on my Oneplus is running OxygenOS and the corresponding Settings UI, don't really know if it's possible to do this on a Realm device, but probably searching for this on the internet could help u find the solution to your problem

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your time and suggestions :)

Comment: your welcome, hope it helps a bit! ;)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

Go to your WhatsApp app > Settings > Notification > Conversation tones and turn conversation tones off. Your music will start working just fine even when you're sending messages.